# Iptables masquerade rules removed, still existing connections alive

Tags: linux, networking, iptables

I have a LAN configuration where iptables masquerade rule is applied on the gateway to enable internet access for the machines in the LAN. Its working fine, however the existing connections are still alive even after removing the masquerade rule. eg: `ping 8.8.8.8` continues on the machines in the LAN even after the masquerade rule is removed. It does not work when pinged again. So existing connections are not killed on removal of the masquerade rule. The rule I added is:

`iptables -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE`

Any suggestions to modify this rule / other solutions to kill the existing connections. ?

Comment: Looks like we need to run a program to kill the established connections

Comment: Could you provide the result of the command "cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward". It should be equal to 0 to stuck the ip forward.

Comment: I have enabled IP forward, otherwise the traffic from the LAN interface wont be forwarded to the WAN interface. Its 1.

Answer (score 2):

As long as the conntrack entry exists (30 timeout for icmp (ping)), the nat table isn't used anymore. It's just short-circuited by the conntrack entry.

You can inspect this behaviour in realtime with `conntrack -E` (install the conntrack package if you don't have the command). Every `[NEW]` entry means a new flow appeared and the nat table was read once. Then it's not used anymore.

To remove this remaining entry, use `conntrack -D` [...] . Check the manual. So for example after removing the MASQUERADE rule while having a ping to 8.8.8.8 still working, doing:

```
conntrack -D  --orig-dst 8.8.8.8
```

should derail this ping. Beware, your internal IP will leak to internet (until it's blocked by a router not liking a non-routable source ip on internet).

Other way to kill the connection without removing the MASQUERADE rule:

Note that NAT isn't intended for firewalling. That using NAT usually protects like a firewall is just a side effect. You should use the filter table to prevent traffic.

Very early in the FORWARD chain, and if it exists, before the usual `-m conntrack --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT` put (a jump to) a new chain called for example blacklist. In this chain simply insert any rule that will match the current connection you want to kill, be it a specific source ip, destination ip, port, ... You can also make use of the `set` module and the `ipset` command. See the example in `man iptables-extensions` : `iptables -A FORWARD -m set --match-set test src,dst` just put it in the blacklist chain instead and add a `-j DROP`.